# Java альтернативная RLE-распаковка

Tags: java, rle

Есть метод, осуществляющий распаковку строки а-ля 2AB3C в AABCCC

```
private static String unpack(String s) {
        StringBuilder counter = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                counter.append(s.charAt(i));
            } else {
                int lim = counter.length() == 0 ? 1 : Integer.parseInt(counter.toString());
                for (int j = 0; j < lim; j++){
                    result.append(s.charAt(i));
                }
                counter = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        return (result);
    }
```

Как следует его изменить, чтобы получилось распаковывать строку, где число повторов указано за числом символов, а не перед ним, то есть A2BC3 в AABCCC?

Comment: Вы уже задавали этот вопрос

Comment: никак нет, тогда распаковка была той, что в первой строке

Comment: да, простите там слегка по-другому, и код из того ответа =)

Comment: вот блин и пытаюсь понять, как бы поменять местами определитель числа повторов и повторяемый символ...

Comment: а как оно должно себя вести когда слева число?

Comment: такого в прицнипе не должно быть, ввод всегда правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так, запоминая последний не числовой символ, и добавляя его только после того как найден следующий не числовой символ:

```
private static String unpack(String s) {
    StringBuilder counter = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String last = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            counter.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else {
            fill(counter, result, last);
            counter = new StringBuilder();
            last = ""+s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    fill(counter, result, last);
    return result.toString();
}

private static void fill(StringBuilder counter, StringBuilder result, String last) {
    int lim = counter.length() == 0 ? 1 : Integer.parseInt(counter.toString());
    for (int j = 0; j < lim; j++){
        result.append(last);
    }
}
```

Comment: получается, что если в конце символ без числа, то он не прибавляется в выходную строку

Comment: @Клаус значит иф надо убрать, я отошел от ide:)

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!